# How to insert or update multi object as a big statement in Django

Tags: database, django, insert

I have a list object need to insert or update on Django server. How can I make it process as one time with one execution (as a big statement). Anyone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For updates you can use QuerySet's [update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) method:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()
qs.update(my_field=value)
```

And for inserts, [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
    Entry(headline="Django 1.0 Released"),
    Entry(headline="Django 1.1 Announced"),
    Entry(headline="Breaking: Django is awesome")
])
```

Remember that `bulk_create()` and `update()` methods will not send any signals like the `save()` method.

Comment: Also `MyModel.objects.filter(foo=bar).update(my_field=value)`